# Include an external library to use under original window context inside content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I'm learning how to convert a userscript that I originally wrote for Tampermonkey to an actual chrome extension.

The goal for this little extension is to get a videojs object on a streaming site that I can control playback remotely with the help of socket.io library.

However, I'm kind of stuck on the first step because I have trouble getting the socket.io (client-side) library to load and use it alongside with my script.

My original **user script** looks like this (the require tag takes care of import for me):

```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
    // @version      0.2
    // @match        https://a.video.site.com/*
    // @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js
    // @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/randomcolor/0.5.4/randomColor.min.js
    // @grant        unsafeWindow
    // @grant        GM_addStyle
    // ==/UserScript==
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        ...

        var socket = io(prod, {
            path: '/',
```

What I have for my chrome extension project 
**content.js**

```
var lib = document.createElement("script");
lib.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("lib/socket.io.js");
document.body.appendChild(lib);

var internalScript = document.createElement("script");
internalScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("injected.js");
document.body.appendChild(internalScript);
```

**manifest.json**

```
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "web_accessible_resources": ["lib/socket.io.js", "injected.js"],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://a.video.site.com/*"],
    "js": ["js/content.js"]
  }]
}
```

The **injected.js** is pretty much the same as my original userscript. However, it can't seem to find the io object from socket.io library.

```
var socket = io(prod, {
            path: '/',
            ...
```

```
injected.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

Is there a good way to inject external libraries under the same context as the original window? I can't seem to find a good tutorial that teaches you how to convert a user script to Chrome extension.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: 1) Try waiting for the first script: lib.onload = () => document.body.appendChild(internalScript), 2) the problem may be that socket.io wants to load other scripts so maybe you'll have to load them too or use a bundled version or even load from the remote url as you did originally

Comment: @wOxxOm I have tried the first option. It still says the same error as before. I'm kind of confused why adding an external script through a cdn is so much more difficult than using the include tag with Tampermonkey.

Comment: Uhm, because userscripts were created specifically to facilitate these kind of things.